# Disable ASUS Vivobook S15 S532F ScreenPad on login page

Tags: linux-mint, login, window-manager, touchpad, asus

I'm new in Linux world, i've just installed it on my Asus Vivobook S15 (i chose Linux Mint because of its simplicity, sometimes...). The problem is that my ScreenPad won't turn off on the login page, even though it's turned off in the system settings (in fact it's disabled when logged in). It also generates an unpleasant graphic effect, I attach the photo.
Can anyone help me? Thanks!
[image]